# Apex Compile Error: sObject type 'Book__c' is not supported

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am new in apex programming. I am using site.com.
I am creating New apex class using this code --

```
@isTest 
private class HelloWorldTestClass {
    static testMethod void validateHelloWorld() {
       Book__c b = new Book__c(Name='Behind the Cloud', Price__c=100);
       System.debug('Price before inserting new book: ' + b.Price__c);

       // Insert book 

       insert b;

       // Retrieve the new book 

       b = [SELECT Price__c FROM Book__c WHERE Id =:b.Id];
       System.debug('Price after trigger fired: ' + b.Price__c);

       // Test that the trigger correctly updated the price 

       System.assertEquals(90, b.Price__c);
    }
}
```

but it gives me this error -Error: **Compile Error: sObject type 'Book_*c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '*_c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 13 column 12.**

help me out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you actually created such object in your Salesforce instance? There are some standard objects (like `User`) and you most likely also have the objects related to the CRM product (like `Account`, `Contact`, `Opportunity`) but `Book__c` will be a custom object created by you or another System Administrator in your organization.

Check Setup (upper right corner in web interface) -> Create -> Objects. There's a [youtube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uD5t8rCvqlE) or you can always click "Help for this page" link.

To expose this object on the Site (which means anybody in the world will be able to view and insert Books) you'll have to follow [few more steps](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/siteforce_data_overview.htm). But as it's a test class that fails to compile I think you haven't reached this problem yet. More info about permissions: http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/siteforce_data_access_perms.htm

Comment: Hi @Learner, does that mean it helped? Cool. What exactly are you trying to do, do you really need to store books in your system or was it just something copied from a tutorial or blog post?